# How to download a file from Azure Blob Storage using Telit cell module (ME910G1)?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, at-command, telit

I am attempting to download a file from Azure Blob Storage using a Telit ME910G1 cell module, and in this case a simple text file (mN.txt) to try the easy, simple case.   Unfortunately, I must not have the correct syntax for the Telit module in regards to the AT commands.  Can someone help me with the AT commands?

I have looked through documentation (PDFs) from Telit, and also tried searches from Microsoft, but I have not found much to answer this question.

I have generated a SAS token and URL from the Azure Storage website, however the Telit module is not happy with it.  Here is an example AT command session (a few characters have been changed for security purposes) where I am trying to download a file called mN.txt:

AT#SGACT=1,1
#SGACT: xx.xx.xx.xxx,

OK

AT#HTTPCFG=0, "https://dvwlxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/dvwlxxxx/mN.txt?sp=r&st=2023-12-18T15:04:38Z&se=2023-12-18T23:04:38Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=dh467YZWk9jET8ThAZcK6ojhbsoOsmsYWA8P2gXA3Go%3D",80,0,,,0,120,1
+CME ERROR: operation not allowed

If I instead try it with a shorter URL it appears to work.  It almost seems like there is a limit on the URI string length.  I tried making a TinyURL with the full URL and tried again:

AT#HTTPCFG=0,"https://xxxxurl.com/5bxsvmut",80,0,,,0,120,1
OK

The next step according to the documentation from Telit would be to send an HTTP GET request with their AT#HTTPQRY command like this:

AT#HTTPQRY=0,0,"/"
+CME ERROR: can not resolve DN

AT#HTTPQRY=0,0,"/mN.txt"
+CME ERROR: can not resolve DN

I am not exactly sure what to put for the final parameter in the HTTPQRY command since the URL has the full file in the name.  I tried the "/" like Telit has in the AT command manual examples, but I had no luck.

Any advice here?

I am able to download the google home page.

AT#HTTPCFG=0,"www.google.com",80,0,,,0,120,1
OK
AT#HTTPQRY=0,0,"/"
OK

#HTTPRING: 0,200,"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",0